# Images not loading after Firebase hosting deployed

Tags: firebase, vue.js

So, I am building this SPA website using mainly Vuejs. Anyway, everything works fine when I build the website through Webpack and its dev server. After deploying it with Firebase hosting, however, the images stop loading.

You can visit the website here, and see for yourself: https://tasker-2d87e.firebaseapp.com/
As you can see, only the favicon loads. The logo, and the hamburger icon do not load with the favicon.

Here's the firebase config:

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Additionally, if you go to the "resources" tab of Chrome's Dev Tool, you can see the 2 images inside the webpack folder.

[image]

I just want to know why the images weren't loading, and if there are any ways to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URLs are looking for a subfolder named `/dist/`, but the public folder is indeed dist, so you just need to take that out of the image tags.

For example, replace https://tasker-2d87e.firebaseapp.com/dist/tasker_logo.png with https://tasker-2d87e.firebaseapp.com/tasker_logo.png and you'll see the image you're looking for.

Comment: Hi. Yes, directly editing it in Chrome's Dev Tool console works! But how do I edit the link directly inside the html/css? Because I put the links as relative, I think webpack automatically makes it static for me.

Comment: Update: I got it working by setting the public path to '/' instead of '/dist/' in webpack.config.js

Answer (score 1):

I found that the filenames served on Firebase are case sensitive. I had **image.jpg** in my code, but the file name was actually **image.JPG** and when I corrected that, everything appeared as expected.